# Onion has yellow center. Is it safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, onions

I cut open an onion I had and it had a yellow center. I read online it might be a sign of sprouting but I am uncertain if that's actually the case. Is it safe to eat? Should I just throw the onion away?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sprouted onions are perfectly **safe** to eat. If far advanced the texture may not be ideal; yours does not sound very far advanced at all (not even green.) Considering you can eat green onions, there's nothing to fear from onion sprouts.